# Using multiple solutions for each page of a Blazor website

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, blazor

We are currently on planning our architecture of creating an ASP.NET Core based website. We have different ASP.NET Core applications (Microservices) which have different jobs. Let's take two of them as an example for this case. One of them is handling the database we use (adds, deletes or edits something e.g.) and another service does collect results of another interface.

Now we had the idea to use Blazor as a framework to display everything. But in a way, that every service does have its own "website" with only one page, where everything each service needs to do can be done or can be seen.

Should be possible I guess. Now the part I am not sure of: There should be a third ASP.NET Core project that has something like a main menu to redirect to the microservice's "websites". Is that possible? If yes, is it recommended to do it this way or is it better to have all pages in the main menu'ed project and to collect the data from the microservices by using http requests and to display them?

To make it quick, this would be the projects we would have:

- The one that collects data from a database having one styled Razor page
- The one that collects data from another interface having one styled Razor page
- The one that has a main menu to redirect to the styled Razor pages of the other two projects

EDIT
I forgot to say that I would like to have a menu on the right side on any site I visit of them. Like, if I try to compare it with WPF, that you have a main view that has a menu but you show other views in a frame.
/EDIT

It's the first time I work with ASP.NET Core or with webservices. If something I said doesn't make sense to you, I'm sorry. Let me know and I will try to explain it in an understandable way.

Comment: Instead of Blazor, think React# - Blazor's object model is quite similar to React. It contains *components* that can come from other projects or call different services. Just like any other SPA by the way. This means you should understand how SPAs and React work. Trying to use WPF as a model is a bad idea

Comment: A Blazor app, just like React, is a hierarchy of components from the root all the way to individual HTML elements. So there's no `all pages in the main menu` - in fact the menu is one more component displaying either static data, data retrieved from a service or data passed from its *parent*

Comment: Thank you for your answer @PanagiotisKanavos. I get your point with the pages, but to be honest I am still unsure what makes React# in comparison better than Blazor in your opinion. Could you explain that a little bit more, please?

Comment: That's not what I said. I said that Blazor **is** React#. It uses the same component model, same way of top-down-only state propagation. It's nothing like WPF. *Blazor* uses components from the root all way down to HTML. It does so in the same way React does though. Even the router that directs actions to specific "pages' (components actually) is a component, living right bellow the App component

Comment: After re-reading your reply, I get it. Sorry. Thank you!
Now I am curious why my question has been downvoted. Is there anything I can do better next time?

Comment: One thing is certain: it takes a lot of adjusting. You'll find several questions in SO when people tried to treat a Blazor component like a WPF UserControl and then wondered why the page wouldn't update after a service call, or why it was so difficult for one component to talk to "siblings".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do exactly what you're proposing in regards to have a main menu that navigates to the other two projects, but I think it also depends on your exact requirements if this is necessary. The other option you have is to only make the back-end microservices and keep the front-end all one application. I think it really depends on how far down the "microservice" architecture you want to go and if the benefits outweigh the time it will take to stand up the projects. Link below that helps explain different thoughts on which idea may be better.

Let me know what you think!

https://micro-frontends.org/

Comment: That sounds very interesting. I didn't think about searching for Micro Frontends. I'm sure this will help. Thank you!

Comment: After talking to my workmates we decided to try to go the way you suggested using micro-frontends. Thank you again!

Comment: @theoneandonlyprogrammer no problem, happy to help!